# how can I add an infowindow to a data layer in Google maps Api

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with adding an info window to a data layer that has data from a geojson link. as my code below will show I can't seem to get the info window to pop-up.

I have used the tutorial found on this [site](https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/dh150/tutorials/google-maps-and-geojson-adding-an-infowindow)

here is my code, I hope you guys can help me. if something is unclear don't hesitate to ask me!

```
    <title>Google Maps IKGEO</title>

    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
        }
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }
        li {
            float: left;
        }
        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        li a:hover:not(.active) {
            background-color: #111;
        }
        .active {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
        }
        .footer {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #333;
            color: aliceblue;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #legend {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 25px;
            margin: 25px;
            border: 3px solid #000;
        }
        #legend h3 {
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        #legend img {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #controls ul{
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="about.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="legend">
        <h2>Legend</h2>
        <div id="controls">
            <ul>
                <il><input type="checkbox" id="data_layer1"></il><img src="Markers/parkinggarage.png"><h3>Parkeerplaats</h3>
                <il><input type="checkbox" id="data_layer2"></il><img src="Markers/supermarket.png"><h3>supermarkt</h3>
                <il><input type="checkbox" id="data_layer3"></il><img src="Markers/bicycle.png"><h3>fietsenstalling</h3>
                <il><input type="checkbox" id="data_layer4"></il><img src="Markers/kiosk.png"><h3>kiosk</h3>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>

        var map;
        var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("data_layer1");
        var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("data_layer2");
        var checkbox3 = document.getElementById("data_layer3");
        var checkbox4 = document.getElementById("data_layer4");

        function initMap() {
            // centrum van de map wanneer deze geladen wordt met een zoom van 12
            var mapOptions = {
                center: {lat: 52.0704978, lng: 4.3006999000000405},
                zoom: 13,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                styles: [
                    {
                    stylers: [
                    { hue: '#fff300' },
                    { invert_lightness: true },
                    { saturation: -100  },
                    { lightness: 33 },
                    { gamma: 0.5 }
                    ]
                    }, {
                      featureType: 'poi.business',
                      elementType: ' labels.icon',
                      stylers: [
                        { visibility: 'on' },
                        { hue: '#fff300' },
                        { lightness: -15 },
                        { saturation: 99 }
                      ]
                    }, {
                      featureType: 'water',
                elementType: 'geometry',
                stylers: [
                    { color: '#456596' },
                    { lightness: 15 }
                      ]
                    }, {
                      featureType: 'transit.station.rail',
                      elementType: 'labels.text.stroke',
                      stylers: [
                      { visibility: 'on' },
                      { color: '#FF6666' }
                      ]
                    }, {
                      featureType: 'poi',
                      elementType: 'geometry',
                      stylers: [
                        { visibility: 'on' },
                        { lightness: -10 }
                      ]
                    }, {
                      featureType: 'road.local',
                      elementType: 'geometry.fill',
                      stylers: [
                        { visibility: 'on' },
                        { hue: '#FFF333' },
                        { lightness: 30 },
                        { saturation: 99 }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
            // variabelen om de datastyle aan te passen per geoJson file
            var data_layer1 = new google.maps.Data({map: map});
            var data_layer2 = new google.maps.Data({map: map});
            var data_layer3 = new google.maps.Data({map: map});
            var data_layer4 = new google.maps.Data({map: map});

            // dit is de wijkgrenzen data (geen style nodig)
            map.data.loadGeoJson('http://geoportaal-ddh.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/cc985cc50ff64b13b744ddaeec613cf9_1.geojson');

            // dit is de parkeercentrum data (Met de style atribuut)
            data_layer1.loadGeoJson('http://geoportaal-ddh.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/fc8de486a74d4b66bcd84d453c5f82c4_1.geojson');
            data_layer1.setStyle({
                icon: 'Markers/parkinggarage.png',
                title: 'parkeercentrums'
            });

            // supermarkten in omgeving Den Haag (Met de style atribuut)
            data_layer2.loadGeoJson('http://geoportaal-ddh.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/d94624fffb6049718469f6f361863f92_0.geojson');
            data_layer2.setStyle({
                icon: 'Markers/supermarket.png',
                title: 'supermarkt'
            });

            // fietsenstalling in omgeving Den Haag (Met de style atribuut)
            data_layer3.loadGeoJson('http://geoportaal-ddh.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3ced9e81a5e048cebb989a64e12037b0_0.geojson');
            data_layer3.setStyle({
                icon: 'Markers/bicycle.png',
                title: 'fietsenstalling'
            });

            // kiosks en straat markten (Met de style atribuut)
            data_layer4.loadGeoJson('http://geoportaal-ddh.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/e070456a09a942acbee3927f30174114_5.geojson');
            data_layer4.setStyle({
                icon: 'Markers/kiosk.png',
                title: 'kiosk en markt',
                type: 'kiosk en markt'
            });

            var icons = {
                parking: {
                    name: 'Parkingcentrum',
                    icon: 'Markers/parkinggarage.png'
                },
                supermarkten: {
                    name: 'supermarkten',
                    icon: 'Markers/supermarket.png'
                },
                kiosk: {
                    name: 'kiosk en markt',
                    icon: 'Markers/kiosk.png'
                },
                fietsenstalling: {
                    name: 'fietsenstalling',
                    icon: 'Markers/bicycle.png'
                }
            };

            var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
                'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
                'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
                'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
                '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
                'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
                'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
                'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
                'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
                'Heritage Site.</p>'+
                '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
                'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
                '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';


            checkbox1.checked = true;
            checkbox2.checked = true;
            checkbox3.checked = true;
            checkbox4.checked = true;

            checkbox1.onclick = function() {
                if (!this.checked) {
                  data_layer1.setMap(null);
                }
                else
                {
                  data_layer1.setMap(map);
                }
            };

            checkbox2.onclick = function() {
                if (!this.checked) {
                  data_layer2.setMap(null);
                }
                else
                {
                  data_layer2.setMap(map);
                }
            };

            checkbox3.onclick = function() {
                if (!this.checked) {
                  data_layer3.setMap(null);
                }
                else
                {
                  data_layer3.setMap(map);
                }
            };

            checkbox4.onclick = function() {
                if (!this.checked) {
                  data_layer4.setMap(null);
                }
                else
                {
                  data_layer4.setMap(map);
                }
            };

            map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(legend);

            var infowindow1 = new google.maps.infoWindow();

            data_layer1.addListener('click', function(event) {
                infowindow1.setContent(contentString);
                infowindow1.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().get());
                infowindow1.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)});
                infowindow1.open(map)
            });
        }


    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAVbOZ-baAJyXl2XwA3pTMskXrOmEEizEM&callback=initMap" async defer>
    </script>

    <div class="footer">
        <p> Disclaimer alle data is open source en is toegestemd voor gebruik </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

my new code:

http://jsbin.com/qamoyepaho/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught TypeError: google.maps.infoWindow is not a constructor` (javascript is case sensitive, should be `InfoWindow`, with a capital 'I')

Comment: thanks this really helped me but I still can't put a infowindow on my data layers

Comment: That typo is still in the posted code.  What errors do you see in your javascript console? It works for me if I fix that error (at least on "layer1", which is the only layer that has the click listener to open the InfoWindow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this:

```
data_layer1.loadGeoJson('http://geoportaal-ddh.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/fc8de486a74d4b66bcd84d453c5f82c4_1.geojson');
data_layer1.setStyle({
  icon: 'Markers/parkinggarage.png',
  title: 'parkeercentrums'
});
```

to:

```
data_layer1.loadGeoJson('http://geoportaal-ddh.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/fc8de486a74d4b66bcd84d453c5f82c4_1.geojson', null, function() {
   addDataLayerListeners(data_layer1, 'parkeercentrums');
});
data_layer1.setStyle({
   title: 'parkeercentrums'
});
```

I removed the `icon` property from the style object because it would cause the markers to not get drawn on the map. I also specified a callback function for each `loadGeoJson` method call. This function is run once the Geo JSON data has finished loading. The callback function executes the `addDataLayerListeners` function and passes it the data layer and the title of the data layer. The `addDataLayerListeners` is defined as:

```
function addDataLayerListeners(data_layer, infoWindowContent) {
 data_layer.addListener('click', function(event) {
   infowindow.setContent(infoWindowContent);
   infowindow.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().get());
   infowindow.setOptions({
     pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
   });
   infowindow.open(map)
 });
}
```

It takes in the data layer object (`data_layer`) and a string to be used for the content of the info window (`infoWindowContent`). The function adds a click event listener to the data layer object and passes `infoWindowContent` to the `infowindow.setContent` method call.

I also made the info window a global variable and instantiated it in the `initMap` function.
At the top of the code I add

```
var infowindow;
```

and in the `initMap` function I add:

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

I did this so there is only one instance of the info window on the map.

Take a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nicufoj/5/edit?js,output) for a working example.

Comment: great thanks for the help. but there is one problem i need an info window with different content for mij data layers.

would you hapend to know how i can manage this?

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: I don't see the changes you made. Did you try my solution? It should do what you want now.

Comment: i've changed my code (check link under my comment) could you find me a solution that works with my icons ;)

http://jsbin.com/qamoyepaho/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Where are you getting your icons from? You specify `Markers/parkinggarage.png` but there is no Markers folder in JSBin. You need to specify a URL like http://efepae.gr/files4users/images/markers/supermarket.png 
Try replacing `Markers/parkinggarage.png` with the link above and it will work because the icon in the link exists.

Comment: I've used the custom markers locally. So for me the work of course. I wanted to use your solution with custom markers is there a way?

Comment: Add `icon: 'url/to/your/custom/icon'` to the object passed to `data_layer1.setStyle` like you had it before. Make sure your icon exists or else the markers won't show up. Take a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/nicufoj/7/edit?js,output). It uses a custom marker for super markets.

Comment: thanks but now the problem is that the filter in the legend doesn't work :D

Comment: You might have to open up a new question since the filter functionality seems to be unrelated to this question.

Comment: Well it's related in the form that the infowindow has to work with the filter functionality which works without the info window but not with it.

Comment: I still feel like displaying markers and filtering them is two separate concerns. And there is nothing in your original question about filters. Now that your original question has been answered I'd recommend asking a new question. I'll definitely help answer it (share a link to it as a comment here). Also, more of the StackOverflow community will be able to participate and help you solve your issue.

Comment: Hey Lavor, i marked this answer as the final answer. i figured out how to do the filters correctly myself. (it missed the checkbox function haha)

Comment: Thanks  Good job figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, google.maps.infoWindow is not a constructor but google.maps.**I**nfoWindow is.

And the infowindow1 is called from the outside, so create it there

```
var infowindow1;
var contentString;
function initMap() {
    [...]
    infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

document.getElementById('data_layer1').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    infowindow1.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow1.setPosition({lat: 52.0704978, lng: 4.3006999000000405});
    infowindow1.setOptions({pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)});
    infowindow1.open(map)
});
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't seem to work the way you showed above.im still looking for a answer where i can put an infowindow on mij datalayers instead of de map.data....